# Automatically start an application from Edge

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

[image]

I'm running a program from Excel VBA. It is writing a text file to my hard disc. So far so good.

I used to run this program from Internet Explorer with the code below. Since I have Windows 11 installed, VBA automatically opens MS Edge. The program stille runs fine. However, I'm getting an annoying message which means that I have to press Open to continue. As my VBA program runs fully automated, this manual twirk is not tolerable.

Can anybody advise me how to get rid of this interrupting question?

```
Function pubRobo(RobInp, RobOut)
Dim IE As Object, maxTime As Date

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") 'New InternetExplorer
    With IE
        .Visible = False
        .navigate "http://robostorage.blob.core.windows.net/clickonce/PbnPlayer/RoboBridge.PbnPlayer.application?pbnFileName=" & RobInp
    End With
    Set IE = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Automatically opening it would be a security risk.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a solution like below to match where the mouse cursor can be moved by VBA to a location on your computer screen. Have VBA then click the box.

You'll probably need to add a wait timer such as `Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))` or `Do While IE.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop //` to give the popup box time to load.

You may be able to use Selenium for this also.

```
Public Declare Function SetCursorPos Lib "user32" (ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long) As Long
Public Declare Sub mouse_event Lib "user32" (ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dx As Long, ByVal dy As Long, ByVal cButtons As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = &H2
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = &H4
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN As Long = &H8
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP As Long = &H10

Private Sub SingleClick()
  SetCursorPos 100, 100 'x and y position
  mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0
  mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0
End Sub

Private Sub DoubleClick()
  'Double click as a quick series of two clicks
  SetCursorPos 100, 100 'x and y position
  mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0
  mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0
  mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0
  mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0
End Sub

Private Sub RightClick()
  'Right click
  SetCursorPos 200, 200 'x and y position
  mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0
  mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0
End Sub
```

source: https://excelhelphq.com/how-to-move-and-click-the-mouse-in-vba/

Comment: it looked like a nice way. However, sometimes Edge is starting twice and the button is on the 'second' page where I hit the first page. It is extremely annoyging ... my programs worked good for years and it seems I can't use it anymore. 
I tried selenium, but i haven't succeeded to get that one working.

Comment: Same here. Since Edge came out, data scraping in excel has gotten much harder. Also, you should be able to maximize the browser window... if you can do that, it should then become the activate window and jump in front of the second browser